# Is it possible to replace the algorithm of OSPF routing protocol with Ant Colony Optimization?

Tags: algorithm, routes, dijkstra, ant-colony

If it is possible, can you share what you know and suggest where should I start. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is, and the subject is somewhat well-studied. You could start by looking at [AntNet](http://faculty.washington.edu/paymana/swarm/dicaro98-part.pdf), an alternative routing algorithm for the OSPF protocol, based on Ant Colony Optimization (ACO). For details on AntNet performance, see e.g.

- [An adaptive multi-agent routing algorithm inspired by ants behavior](http://faculty.washington.edu/paymana/swarm/dicaro98-part.pdf) (*Gianni Di Caro and Marco Dorigo*)

AntNet has a few years on it though, so you should probably look into some more recent developments in the field. E.g., have a look at multilevel Ant Colony Optimization (MLV-ACO) an its possible applications to OSPF routing. You could start with:

- [Towards a Multilevel Ant Colony Optimisation](http://brage.bibsys.no/xmlui/bitstream/id/242476/Towards%20a%20Multilevel%20Ant%20Colony%20Optimization%20Final%20Report.pdf) (*T.A. Lian et al*)